# FTL: How to retrieve "href" value from <a> link

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker

I am trying to retrieve the **href** value from a link in Freemarker like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="some-class">Test</a>
```

Comment: So, what have You tried so far?

Comment: @Kamiccolo Tried ?matches to select the href. But without luck

Comment: You can use Jsoup, it is used for parsing html pages.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I am looking for a Freemarker specific solution

Comment: @Depzor could you please post the code in which you tried to select the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to retrieve using Pattern. Your may try it

```
String str = "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\" class=\"some-class\">Test</a>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(href=\"(.*?)\")");
Matcher macther = pattern.matcher(str);
if(macther.find()){
    System.out.println(macther.group(1).substring(5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression with groups in the [match](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_matches) builtin.

Example:

```
<#assign res='<a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>'?matches(r'href="(.*?)"')>

<#list res as m>
  ${m?groups[1]}
</#list>
```

This will yield:

```
http://www.example.com
```